# Application.Startup path not working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am writing a code to update a 2003 access database. My connection string is:

```
 Dim connectionstring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Application.startuppath & "\ELSR.mdb"
```

However, I am getting the error that "startuppath is not a member of system.web.httpapplicationstate" I have added the reference to `System.Windows.Forms` and it still isn't working. Any advice?

Thanks!
Sarah

Comment: In short, you can't. Try using `Server.MapPath()` more information here **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx** Also by adding more relevant code would help as well as just the connection string isn't enough. Also you can make a helper function that would return this string which would be best as your probably going to need it again sometime.

Comment: Using server.mappath() I am now getting the error "Argument not specified for parameter 'path' of 'Public Function MapPath(path as string) as string'.

Comment: No, don't add a parameter, create a function that return's the connection string...

Comment: Could you provide code to explain what you mean?
Thank you!

Comment: please see answer for example helper function.

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm having so much trouble with this, but it is unable to locate my file. It has the correct path, and the file is there, but I'm getting an error that says cant locate file

Comment: Hmm is it possible you don't have permission?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the return function and look at the path it return's and make sure it is returning the correct path.

Comment: The path is correct, I have permission, I added the file to visual studio myself. I'm feeling like my version of visual studio isn't supporting this. This should be an easy code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Server.MapPath()` more information here **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx** Also by adding more relevant code would help as well as just the connection string isn't enough. Also you can make a helper function that would return this string which would be best as your probably going to need it again sometime.

**Example Connection Function**

```
 Public Shared Function GetConnection() As String 
    Return "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= " & HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("\ELSR.mdb")
 End Function
```

You can call this like this...

```
 Dim strConn As String = GetFilePath()
```